# custom function with mutate do not work

Tags: r, dplyr

Some custom functions do not work in mutate. Would you explain
why calc2 and calc3 dont work, and how to fix them to work properly?

```
    library(dplyr)
    m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, byrow = T)        

    calc <- function(x1,x2,x3){ #scalar
      return(x1 + x2 + x3)
    }

    calc2 <- function(x){ #vector
      return(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])
    }

    calc3 <- function(x){ #list
      x <- unlist(x)
      return(sum(x))
    }

    as.data.frame(m) %>% 
      mutate(val  = calc(V1,V2,V3), #OK
             val2 = calc2(c(V1,V2,V3) ), #NG
             val3 = calc3(list(V1,V2,V3))) #NG
```

below is the output:

```
    V1 V2 V3 val val2 val3
    1  2  3   6   12   45
    4  5  6  15   12   45
    7  8  9  24   12   45
```

Comment: “do not work” isn’t a very good problem description.

Comment: Could you show your expected output

Comment: akrun, I expect val2 and val3 same as val.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this without changing the OP's functions using `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(m) %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(val = calc(V1, V2, V3), 
                val2 = calc2(c(V1, V2, V3)),
                val3 = calc3(list(V1, V2, V3)))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
#     V1    V2    V3   val  val2  val3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3     6     6     6
#2     4     5     6    15    15    15
#3     7     8     9    24    24    24
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, this is extactly answer I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

This has got nothing to do with dplyr/`mutate`. You’re simply not vectorising properly. Let’s inspect what `calc2` and `calc3` get as input, shall we?

In **`calc2`**, `x = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 9L)`. That is, all elements got concatenated into one vector. And you then add the first three: 1 + 4 + 7 = 12.

In **`calc3`**, `x` makes more sense, except that you then `unlist` it; after that, `x` is the same as above, and then you `sum` all its elements: `sum(x)` = 45.

`calc2` is essentially not salvageable but you can fix `calc3` by vectorising:

```
calc3 = function (x) {
    Reduce(`+`, x)
}
```

And finally, you can get the best of `calc` and `calc3` by using `...` arguments:

```
calc = function (...) {
    Reduce(`+`, list(...))
}
```

Usage:

```
as.data.frame(m) %>% mutate(v = calc(V1, V2, V3))
```

Comment: Mutate functions need to be vectorized. The first function meets this criteria while the others do not.