# Vectorising linear interpolation function for use with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, interpolation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
# Set RNG
set.seed(33550336)

# Create toy data frame
df <- expand.grid(day = 1:10, dist = seq(0, 100, by = 10))

df1 <- df %>% mutate(region = "Here") 
df2 <- df %>% mutate(region = "There") 
df3 <- df %>% mutate(region = "Everywhere") 

df_ref <- do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3))

df_ref$value <- runif(nrow(df_ref))

# > head(df_ref)
#   day dist region      value
# 1   1    0   Here 0.39413117
# 2   2    0   Here 0.44224203
# 3   3    0   Here 0.44207487
# 4   4    0   Here 0.08007335
# 5   5    0   Here 0.02836093
# 6   6    0   Here 0.94475814
```

This represents a reference data frame and I'd like to compare observations against it. My observations are taken on a specific day that is found in this reference data frame (i.e., `day` is an integer from 1 to 10) in a region that is also found in this data frame (i.e., `Here`, `There`, or `Everywhere`), but the distance (`dist`) is *not* necessarily an integer between 0 and 100. For example, my observation data frame (`df_obs`) might look like this:

```
# Observations
df_obs <- data.frame(day = sample(1:10, 3, replace = TRUE), 
                     region = sample(c("Here", "There", "Everywhere")), 
                     dist = runif(3, 0, 100))

# day     region     dist
# 1   6 Everywhere 68.77991
# 2   7      There 57.78280
# 3  10       Here 85.71628
```

Since `dist` is not an integer, I can't just lookup the value corresponding to my observations in `df_ref` like this:

```
df_ref %>% filter(day == 6, region == "Everywhere", dist == 68.77991)
```

So, I created a lookup function that uses the linear interpolation function `approx`:

```
lookup <- function(re, di, da){
  # Filter to day and region
  df_tmp <- df_ref %>% filter(region == re, day == da)

  # Approximate answer from distance
  approx(unlist(df_tmp$dist), unlist(df_tmp$value), xout = di)$y
}
```

Applying this to my first observation gives,

```
lookup("Everywhere", 68.77991, 6)
#[1] 0.8037013
```

Nevertheless, when I apply the function using `mutate` I get a different answer.

```
df_obs %>% mutate(ref = lookup(region, dist, day))
#   day     region     dist       ref
# 1   6 Everywhere 68.77991 0.1881132
# 2   7      There 57.78280 0.1755198
# 3  10       Here 85.71628 0.1730285
```

I suspect that this is because `lookup` is not vectorised correctly. Why am I getting different answers and how do I fix my `lookup` function to avoid this?

Comment: Try `df_obs%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(...)`

Comment: @A.Suliman Problem solved! Want to turn that into an answer? Is there a better way to write my function in a vectorised form or for this sort of thing do I simply have to apply the function rowwise?

Comment: You can check my comment and the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699321/calculate-sunrise-function-that-works-with-dataframe-with-dplyrmutate)